# How to manage composite builds between gradle modules projects and applications

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm facing this [limitation / issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1909) with Gradle.
I have two multi-project builds with Gradle, let's call them `modules-technical`, and `modules-business`.

This is my `setting.gradle` for `modules-business`:

```
rootProject.name = 'modules-business'
include 'business-core'
.. snip business-* modules ..
includeBuild '../modules-technical/'
```

This means, that `modules-business` depends on `modules-technical`.

Now, I want to develop an app that depends on `modules-business`.

```
rootProject.name = 'my-app'
includeBuild '../modules-business'
includeBuild '../modules-technical'
```

Due to the current limitations of Gradle 4.2.1 I would need to comment the `includeBuild` statement on my `modules-business` project. Like this:

```
rootProject.name = 'modules-business'
include 'business-core'
.. snip business-* modules ..
// includeBuild '../modules-technical/'
```

Is there a better way to manage this limitation for now? Meaning, how can I develop multi-modules and applications using Gradle composite builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
if (settings.hasProperty('doCompositeBuilds') && doCompositeBuilds.toBoolean()) {
    includeBuild '../modules-technical/'
}
```

and set `doCompositeBuilds` to `true` when working with `modules-business` and to `false` or leave unset when working with app.

Or you could have two branches of `modules-business`, one with the `includeBuild`, one without and then use the one you actually need.